# How do i convert my users input on my array to base 64?

Tags: java, loops, encryption, while-loop, cryptography

**CODE SAMPLE**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BaseE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter text: ");
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            words.add(sc.nextLine());
            if(sc.nextLine().equals("STOP"))
            {
            break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(words);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the build in Java method:

`Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(String yourString);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Enter text: ");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String userInput = sc.nextLine();
        words.add(userInput);
        String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userInput.getBytes());
        System.out.println("User Input encoded: " + encodedString);
        if (userInput.equals("STOP")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(words);
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

**Note: This is not an encryption in any way but just an encoding and should not be used at all for security purposes!**

Comment: how do i save it as notepad after encrypting? my teacher said to me that the user is allowed to put any text as much as they want. They can also save it in the notepad.

Comment: I assume your teacher means to save it to file: Read this:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file
Please upvote my answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that `base64 encoding` was designed for email attachments using `SMTP` which doesn't support `non-ascii files`.  It is not very efficient for storage in that it always increases the content size by 33%.

Comment: Your b64 encoding function should execute in constant time to mitigate against side-channel attacks